# Check the Font Name in a sheet and if its not Arial the highlight the entire row

Tags: excel, vba

```
For i=1 to Lastrow
If cells(i,1).Worksheets("Name").Font.Name<> "Arial" then
cells(i,1).Entirerow.interior.colorindex= 3
Else cells(i,1).Entirerow.interior.colorindex= 2
End if
Next i
```

This code is not working for me. I want to check if font is Arial and if it is the  don't do anything else highlight the row with red color. Please guide.

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? Does it throw an error or something?

Comment: You need to change the order of `cells(i,1).Worksheets("Name")` to `Worksheets("Name").Cells(i, 1)`. Also, change `cells(i,1).Entirerow` to `Worksheets("Name").Rows(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order of `cells(i,1).Worksheets("Name")` to [`Worksheets("Name").Cells(i, 1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-cells-property-excel).

Also, change `cells(i,1).Entirerow` to [`Worksheets("Name").Rows(i)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-rows-property-excel).

I would also advise using a `With Worksheets("Name")`.

Result:

```
With Worksheets("Name")
  For i = 1 to Lastrow
    If .Cells(i, 1).Font.Name<> "Arial" then
      .Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex= 3
    Else
      .Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex= 2
    End if
  Next i
End With
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with using EntireRow as far as I know?

Comment: @SJR Nothing. I just prefer this way. :)

Comment: You should move the `With` outside the `For` loop.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - why, is it more efficient?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I guess you're right. I'm not sure if it make any difference after "compiled" so I had made its scope as small as needed, but it might be opening and closing in every iteration. Edit: ops, I mention the wrong person.

Comment: @sjr  yes, it is.  Since the With block object is not dependant on the For loop iterator, doing it once outside the loop will be faster

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @chrisneilsen

Answer (score 1):

@user7393973 has identified your main problem, but you could avoid the If this way.

```
Sub x()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To Lastrow
    Worksheets("Name").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = IIf(Worksheets("Name").Cells(i, 1).Font.Name = "Arial", 2, 3)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That's optional to any `If...Else...End If`, but I will upvote your answer regardless.

Comment: Second thought, maybe it wouldn't be ideal if there were multiple different instructions, so yes, it isn't optional to any, so that's a good use of it.

Comment: Yes, to clarify this approach is best if you have only two choices, though you can nest Iif statements. However I would recommend sticking with If or using Select Case for more complicated scenarios.

Comment: This is more of a small question, but would using `Integer` be better or is there edge cases where it wouldn't work? My Excel 2013 has 1 048 576 rows per sheet.

Comment: No, it's better to use Long in (pretty much) all circumstances. In any case Integer is generally converted to Long "behind the scenes", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long

Comment: When I removed lastrow with a number its working for me. Please guide why lastrow was not being considered by VBA?

Comment: How are you defining it and what is it’s value?